# Is there a way to check the ip's through which my gcp is logged in?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to check if there is any to find out from which ip addresses my gcp account is logged in. I want to know how do we check that. I want to check the whole login activity of my account with the IP addressed.

Let me know if anyone has any idea. this woudl be a great help.

Thanks!

Comment: Users do not log into the Google Cloud Platform. They log into Google Accounts, which stores a token in the user's browser. AFAIK the only information you can access for your own account is [here](https://myaccount.google.com/).

Comment: This is a somewhat unusual question that might suggest a misunderstanding of how web services work, but if not, it would be very helpful to explain why you wish to determine the IP addresses associated with your session. And what you feel this means to you (as there is a chance the paradigm you are exploring is not in sync with the actual implementation of a platform like GCP).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.